# Dúvidas de quais métodos de IA utilizar (regressão linear, segmentação, redes neurais)

Tags: inteligência-artificial, tensorflow

Peço desculpa por parecer uma pergunta boba, comecei a estudar IA e machine learning esse ano e ainda estou estudando sobre isso. O principal motivo é quero quero elaborar um projeto e me desafiei a isso.
Está difícil eu "entender como elaborar o modelo e o que devo usar", estou lendo artigos, mas mesmo assim isso não entra na minha cabeça.

Exemplificando o que quero fazer, **tenho as seguintes tabelas:**

- Tabela clientes.
- Tabela Pedidos desses clientes(Com a lista de produtos e data que eles efetuaram a compra).
- Tabela de produtos.

Também é possível obter média de venda, produtos mais vendidos etc...

Mas digamos que eu queira saber se uma ação de propaganda de um determinado **produto** direcionada a um determinado grupo de **clientes** terá qual efeito sobre as **vendas**.

### Agora irei falar o que pensei em fazer:

- Pegar os pedidos desses clientes e fazer um média de compras desses produtos(por mês ou dia), assim terei informação sobre a quantidade que esses clientes compram. Eu poderia então fazer uma regressão linear desse cliente em relação ao produto e "prever" a próxima compra dele. E depois fazer uma "segmentação?" para dividir em grupos baseado quais produtos se tendem a comprar no próximo período, valor gasto mensal e prever quais outros produtos tende a compram "junto" com o produto principal.
- Aplico "regressão linear?" sobre grupos de clientes e suas tendencias de compra, assim vejo qual foi a "porcentagem" de alteração de média vendas recorrente pela propaganda.
- Assim consigo prever qual vai ser a porcentagem de relevância de uma propaganda de determinado produto a um grupo de clientes.

Então, o que estou errando e o que estou acertando? O que seria melhor?

Eu pensei em usar redes neurais com tensorflow, mas não consegui fazer os exemplos disponíveis porque a maioria é baseado em reconhecimento de imagem, coisa que não tenho interesse nesse momento, queria algo mais empresarial, utilizando dados de banco tipo vendas. (se tiverem exemplo agradeço)

Sobre regressão linear, é possível utilizar strings e atribuir valores? digamos que o tipo "professores" compram mais giz que o tipo "alunos".

Se tiver algum artigo que possa ajudar, agradeço! De qualquer forma ainda vou ter que estudar bastante...

Comment: Bom dia Maicon... Acredito que sim, a regressão linear é utilizado para você estimar qual a porcentagem de um determinado cenário sobre outro cenário... exemplo, quer saber qual a porcentagem de pessoas que fumavam, em um quantidade de pessoas que tiveram câncer.